# I am getting js.experimental-foreign-object-prototype while running Karate tests

Tags: javascript, karate, graalvm

I get this error when I run a karate test:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find option with name js.experimental-foreign-object-prototype.
Did you mean one of the following?
    js.foreign-object-prototype=<Boolean>
        at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineException.illegalArgument(PolyglotEngineException.java:131)
```

I have `GraalVM 22` and it has `JS` also.

I think, there is some option missing in my local environment, because the tests run on the server.

Comment: most certainly a jdk version or library conflict issue. follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - or troubleshoot yourself, some hints here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2243

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas for the prompt response, I changed to JDK 11. But the error remains same. Do you have any guesses which version of Java?

Comment: you can try 1.5.0.RC2 which needs Java 17. the reason I suggest this is that it upgrades the Graal dependencies, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2401